# Rename file which uses the first 2 letters of every word

Tags: command-line, rename

I'm currently using a simple script for renaming:

```bsh
for f in *.mp4; do 
    echo mv $f $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM.mp4;
    mv $f $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM.mp4; 
done
```

But instead of using the `$random`, I would like to take the first 2 letters of each word.

*Example*

before renaming:

```
having the best day.jpeg
```

afterr renaming:

```
hathbeda.jpeg
```

---

Ok, a bit trickier :) My filenames mostly have . to seperate the words. Is it still possible to do it than?

Comment: I'd look into using grep, sed, and awk. They allow you to sculpt text.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a single `rename` command (i.e. you don't need a `bash` script for this, or you can use this command within your `bash` script in place of the `for` loop):

```
rename -n 's/(^| )([^ ]{1,2})[^ ]*/$2/g; s/$/.mp4/' *.mp4
```

This will just mimic the behavior of `echo mv [...]`, so that you can see the result without actually renaming anything.

If the result is the expected one, then run:

```
rename 's/(^| )([^ ]{1,2})[^ ]*/$2/g; s/$/.mp4/' *.mp4
```

**Command breakdown**:

- `rename`: renames multiple files using `PCRE`s
- `*.mp4`: renames only files with extension `.mp4`

**Regex #1 breakdown**:

- `s`: performs a substitution
- `/`: starts the regex
- `(`: starts grouping the allowed strings
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `|`: separates the second allowed string
- : matches a  character
- `)`: stops grouping the allowed strings
- `(`: starts the second capturing group
- `[^ ]{1,2}`: matches from 1 to 2 occurrences of any character not
- `)`: stops the second capturing group
- `[^ ]*`: matches any number of characters not
- `/`: stops the regex / starts the replacement
- `$2`: replaces with the second capturing group
- `/`: stops the replacement
- `g`: replaces all the pattern occurences in the line

**Regex #2 breakdown**:

- `s`: performs a substitution
- `/`: starts the regex
- `$`: matches the end of the line
- `/`: stops the regex / starts the replacement
- `.mp4`: adds a `.mp4` string
- `/`: stops the replacement

Comment: Always recommend running `rename` with `-n`, then remove the `-n`  if results are satisfactory. (Also consider `\S` and `\s` in place of `[^ ]` and space.)

Comment: It's munching extension when I test on `having the best day.jpeg`

Answer (score 1):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import glob, os
for filename in glob.glob('*.jpeg'):
    first = filename.split('.')
    second = first[0].split(' ')
    name = ''
    for i in range(0, len(second)):
        name += second[i][:2]
    os.rename(filename, name + '.' + first[1]
```

- `first` is the list containing the parts of filename splitted on the `.` (assuming you have only one `.` in the filename)
- `second` is the list having the filename upto the `.` splitted on spaces.
- Next we go though the contents of the `second` to take out the first two characters out of it and then adding them together to get the first part of our new filename
- Then we have used `os.rename` to rename the file accordingly by adding `.jpeg` at the end of `name`.

Also note that, the destination file must not exist beforehand, if it exists it will be overwritten.

**Test:**

**Before**:

```
$ ls -1
foo.jpeg
having the best day.jpeg
hello kitty cat spam.jpeg
this is a doggy.jpeg
```

**After:**

```
$ ls -1
fo.jpeg
hathbeda.jpeg
hekicasp.jpeg
thisado.jpeg
```